# Word for giving a name to something to legitimize it

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word or logical fallacy for describing the action of giving something a name to legitimize it?

Here's a simple example:

> Alice: Your jeans are too tight
>
> Bob: No, they're *slim jeans*

The word should also work to describe something like this

> Alice: I told her she's overreacting
>
> Bob: You're *invalidating* her feelings

Ideally, I would want a single word to describe this action because it would circularly serve as an example of its meaning.
Just like how the word *grandiloquent* is an example of grandiloquent language.

Comment: Neither of those examples really makes sense to me. *Slim jeans* are not called *slim* because they're too tight. (That seems more like a pun to me than anything else.) And the word *invalidating* seems antithetical to the concept of *legitimizing* anything.

Comment: I agree that the examples may be missing some context. The point is not that Bob is correct/incorrect in either case. It's that Bob is using a word that describes the situation as an argument.

Comment: This is sort of *reification*, though perhaps not exactly.